Error when migrating from System.Data.SqlClient to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
I'm updating a Winforms application to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient from System.Data.SqlClient. The version of the .NET Framework on the project needed to be updated from 4.6.1 to 4.8. I keep getting errors related to DLL files when trying to open the connection.
Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

' Open the connection
connection.Open()

The error below happens on the using statement.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The version of System.Memory attached to the project is the latest version (4.5.5). I have updated all the NuGet packages installed to their latest versions. I have created a simple application to test this code and it does work there but it does not work when trying to update the legacy application.
How can I fix this error?

System.Memory is one of the "msbuild kinda makes a mess of this on .NET Framework" group - does your top-level application project have an explicit project reference to System.Memory? or are you relying on the transitive reference?

Have you tried delete the BIN and OBJ folders in the solution? Sometimes when I get weird errors like that, this will fix it. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CleanSolution  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Clean-Solution-should-clear-obj-and-bin/10555328?sort=newest

I'm updating a Winforms application to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient: Is there a particular reason you're changing it?

I'm moving from using SQL authentication on the database to Entra authentication. System.Data.SqlClient doesn't support this. I did try deleting the BIN and OBJ folders but I still get the error.

Try creating a new solution and copy objects from the old one.

I did create a console application and a Winforms application to test that the approach I was taking would work. I didn't have any issues with those projects

The solution I was using has a number of projects in it. The project where I was using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient was not the startup project. When I added Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to the startup project using NuGet, even though it was not being used there, that seems to have fixed the issue.
